# Coding a new variable according to the range of existing variables

Tags: r, debugging, variables, if-statement

I wrote the code below using "ifelse" function, 
which only returns "worker" to a$age_group , the new column I want to create according to the variable "age" but only.

I don't know why... can you help me debug my code?

```
for(i in 1:length(a$age))
{
    ifelse(a$age<17, a$age_group<-"mid", 
                     ifelse(a$age<20, a$age_group<-"high", 
                                      ifelse(a$age<24, a$age_group<-"univ", 
                                                       a$age_group<-"worker")))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cut` or `findInterval`:

```
with(a, cut(age, breaks=c(17, 20, 24, Inf), 
        labels=c('mid', 'high', 'univ', 'worker'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated and I suspect it might also be quite slow. Keep in mind that `ifelse` is vectorized. So you don't need the `for` loop here. The main problem, however, is that the later calls to `ifelse` are overwriting the earlier ones because you do the assignment inside, you need to put the assignment outside the `ifelse` calls. Try this one:

```
a$age_group <- ifelse(a$age < 17, "mid",
                  ifelse(a$age < 20, "high",
                         ifelse(a$age < 24, "univ", "worker")))
```

Comment: You're right! I updated my answer. It should work now.